# Get Touches on perticular screen in iPhone Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to detect touch began n touch end on particular part of screen. I have a Spider as Sprite and i change its face direction by touchbegan and touchend. and i want to get touch only from front of my spider.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //[self ccTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startTouchPoint = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    //location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
    CCLOG(@"Location of Touch %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(startTouchPoint));
}
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endlocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    if(startTouchPoint.x != endlocation.x && startTouchPoint.y != endlocation.y) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];
        
        [self calcAngleAndRotateObjectStartingAtPoint:sprite_Spider.position endingAtPoint:touchPoint];
    }
}
```

[image]

This is my spider and i want to get touch only in between those red lines. How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would go for UITapGestureRecognizer and implement the delegate method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

In you should return false anywhere between those lines NO and YEs in all other places.

You can also detect different phases of the tap gestures

Comment: but how i will detect tab between those lines?

Comment: write a function that calcualtes returns tyes or no depending on hhe tap posiiton.you can read the gesture point and fromth image you know the coordiantes of the lines

Comment: Those lines are not static. they will change .

Comment: in any case you need to know the area that you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

Make a hypothetical rect in front of spider every time and use this method to detect touch

```
CGRectContainsPoint(<rect>,<point>)
```

Do any thing if touch is within the rect

Comment: is there any example available on CGRectContainsPoint?

Comment: It returns a bool make a rect at the nose of your spider <u have to figure that out> and pass that rect in method along with touch point in an if statement.